# HBASE unknown host while connecting from Java API outside AWS

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to connect to Hbase from java API. I am getting `unknown host error`

```
unknown host: ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX
```

Reason is it's looking for internal IP. I am connecting using Zookeeper's quorum and giving it external IP address. It connects to Zookeeper but then throws error.

Note: I am using Horton works platform.

Comment: Tried with SSH tunneling, I tunneled localhost port to AWS's private IP and it connected to Zookeeper. However, after connecting to zookeeper it's throwing `unknown host` error.